# Meaning of the phrase "Beating on your craft"!

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases

I was translating a document in another language, then I saw this famous quotation from Will Smith that is provided here.

> The separation of talent and skill is one of the greatest
>   misunderstood concepts for people who are trying to excel, who have
>   dreams, who want to do things. Talent you have naturally. Skill is
>   only developed by hours and hours and hours of **beating on your
>   craft**. - *Will Smith*

I don't exactly get the bold part, can anybody paraphrase it for me?

I have checked the Longman Dictionary and also Googled about that, but still, don't understand the meaning of "beating on your craft".

This is the results I found in the dictionary:

> - Beat on/against/at etc: to hit against something many times or continuously.
>
> *example: Rain beating on the windows.*
>
> - Craft: the skill needed in a particular profession.
>
> *example: The musician spends years perfecting his craft.*

I thought that maybe it means when you work and spend hours and hours you are gradually developing your skills like a blacksmith that makes a perfect sword with continuous beats of a hammer.

Is it true?

Comment: hammer away at would have  been better English. Will Smith is not exactly a good speaker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To "beat on" something means to pound or hammer on it. I haven't heard this particular usage before, but "hammering" is often synonymous with *hard work*. "Hammer away at" is an idiom that means to *keep at something continuously*.

Will is basically saying that you need to continually work at your chosen craft to become good at it.

Answer (score -1):

He meant always beating the best version of himself!